# Binding dynamic ContextMenu items with DataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, contextmenu

I have an app which needs a dynamic context menu that can change per item.  The way I implemented this was to create a bindable object with a Name and Command property (I don't want to create UI MenuItem objects in my viewmodel).  I bound the ContextMenu.ItemsSource to this collection and setup a item template and it worked mostly fine, except I didn't get separators.  I changed my approach slightly so I have two DataTemplates defined for one of two model objects and don't set the item template anymore (since it has to switch between menu item and separator templates now).  The problem is that it doesn't use these templates at all now.  I just get the standard ToString on the class items.  My templates are defined in the same file here:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type contracts:BindableMenuItem }">
    <MenuItem DataContext="{Binding}" Header="{Binding MenuItemHeader}" Command="{Binding MenuCommand}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type contracts:BindableMenuSeparator }">
    <Separator />
</DataTemplate>
```

These never get used though.  What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you misunderstand about how `DataTemplate` applies to a type. This type should be a content type which does not inherit from `FrameworkElement` or anything can be rendered itself. So in this case I guess your `BindableMenuItem` and `BindableMenuSeparator` are custom controls? If so `DataTemplate` won't have any effect.

Comment: @KingKing Thanks for the response.  No, these are models, despite the naming.  Not controls at all.  I wanted a model-side representation of things can could end up being bound to real MenuItem controls without referencing UI classes in the viewmodel.  I figured if the ContextMenu.ItemsSource pointed to a collection containing a mixture of both of these types, the DataTemplates would make sure they rendered properly.

Comment: Could you post code one how your viewmodel code looks like, that is, the property with BindableMenuItems (a collection I am guessing?).